# scalding how to map on all fields with '* keyword?

Tags: scala, scalding

I want to apply an operation to all fields of my Pipe. I saw on https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference
that
"You can use '* (here and elsewhere) to mean all fields."
but somehow I do not succeed to make it work. Would someone be kind enough to show me an example ?

initially I have something like

```
mySource.map('field1 -> 'field1){ number: String => number.trim }
```

which I now would like to apply to all fields like something

```
mySource.map('* -> '*){ numbers: List[String] => numbers.map(_.trim) }
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scalding Fields API, in order to map from `'*` to `'*`, best approach I can think of is Cascading `TupleEntry`, [cascading.tuple.TupleEntry](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/javadoc/cascading/tuple/TupleEntry.html)

```
import com.twitter.scalding._
import cascading.tuple.TupleEntry

// Notice I do not specify the scheme when reading.
// I only know first column is 'user_id', the rest is some value and I want 
// to double the values. You can use 'map' or 'mapTo'.
Tsv(args("input"))
  .read
  .map('* -> '*) {
     fields: TupleEntry =>
     val sz: Int = fields.size()
     for (i <- from 1 until sz) fields.setDouble(i, fields.getDouble(i) * 2.0)
     fields.getTuple()
  }
  .write(Tsv(args("output")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'*` operator only seems to work with `mapTo` and full type annotation.

```
mySource
  .mapTo[(String,String,String),(String,String,String)]('* -> '*) { case (a: String, b: String, c: String) =>
    (a.trim, b.trim, c.trim)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example this works with Scalding 0.11.0 (neither of the current answers worked as they are):

```scala
  mySource
    .mapTo('* -> '*) {
      entry: TupleEntry =>
        for (i <- 0 until entry.size) {
          if (entry.getObject(i) == null) entry.setRaw(i, "\\N")
        }
        entry.getTuple
    }
```

So essentially `mapTo('* -> '*)` -> `entry.getTuple`.